# node.js : identify device (desktop/mobile/ipad) os (android/iOS) source (browser/app) on server side using user-agent string

Tags: ios, node.js, sails.js, user-agent

I am trying to decipher this information from user-agent string on a node.js server based on Sails.js framework.

I have access to user-agent in `req.headers["user-agent"]`

Currently I am using this function to segregate iPhone, iPad and Android devices.

```
function findPlatform(userAgent){
  var iphoneReg = /\biphone\b/gi;
  var ipadReg = /\bipad\b/gi;
  var androidReg = /\bandroid\b/gi;

  if(!userAgent){
    sails.log.error("cant infer user agent");
    return "others";
  }
  if(userAgent.search(androidReg) > -1){
    return "android";
  }
  else if(userAgent.search(iphoneReg) > -1){
    return "iphone";
  }
  else if(userAgent.search(ipadReg) > -1){
    return "ipad";
  }
  else {
    return "others";
  }
}
```

However, I also need to segregate between mobile app and mobile browser for both android and iOS. I was looking at certain requests and could see that user-agent from mobile app looks like this:

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; Lenovo A7000-a Build/LRX21M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/45.0.2454.95 Mobile Safari/537.36"
```

While from mobile browser, it looked like this:

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; MI 4W Build/KTU84P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.76 Mobile Safari/537.36"
```

Can I user a regex to match keyword "Version" to identify the request as coming from app ? What about iOS ?

Comment: Why not use a library instead of reinventing this particular wheel?

Comment: Im using the user agent library but still not able to segregate between mobile browser and mobile app